# Directive 'magic_quotes_gpc' is deprecated in PHP 5.3 and greater laravel

Tags: php, laravel

> Directive 'magic_quotes_gpc' is deprecated in PHP 5.3 and greater
>       in laravel

I don't have access to php.ini file at the server so i can't turn magic_quotes off, i have already tried .htaccess method it didn't work.

Comment: Ask your hosting provider to remove that configuration, it's no longer needed in PHP 5.3

Comment: Also nobody can help with "didn't work" unless more specific result messages and PHP setup details are provided (=which SAPI).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should ask your hosting provider to turn off magic quotes.

If you can't do that, you can use this code to remove magic quotes your self:

```
// Remove Magic Quotes

if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $process = array(&$_GET, &$_POST, &$_COOKIE, &$_REQUEST);
    while (list($key, $val) = each($process)) {
        foreach ($val as $k => $v) {
            unset($process[$key][$k]);
            if (is_array($v)) {
                $process[$key][stripslashes($k)] = $v;
                $process[] = &$process[$key][stripslashes($k)];
            } else {
                $process[$key][stripslashes($k)] = stripslashes($v);
            }
        }
    }
    unset($process);
}
```

Just put this code somewhere at bootstrap level, or you should put this as first code in your scripts.

I had similar situation where I had PHP 5.3 and magic quotes turned on.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your website is badly configured. Consult your hosting provider and if they don't turn it off find another host or VPS.